# Suboptimal query plan when updating partitioned table

Tags: postgresql, performance, partitioning, postgresql-10, query-performance

### Background

- I have a simple CTE used to update a declaratively-partitioned table.
- The subquery runs quickly (`1.7sec` per `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`) and returns `3,769` records (CTE `y` in the query below).
- The `UPDATE` seeks to update non-index columns of a declaratively-partitioned table. A few characteristics of the table:

  - Contains `21 million` records
  - `184` partitions -- yes, too many -- each child partition has primary/ foreign keys and indices
  - `fillfactor=100` (plan to reduce to potentially use HOT on same pages, but not certain that query plan affected by lack of page space)

Problem arises upon `UPDATE`, per the incremental query plan shown (`EXPLAIN`)  after the subquery (via CTE) runs (several nested loops of hash joins):

```
-> Hash Join /* Run for each child partition, based on CTE PK = child table PK */
     -> Nested Loop
          -> CTE Scan
          -> Append
               -> Index Scan /* for index on each child partition */
                  ... /* Index scans (for each child partition) */
     -> Hash
          -> Seq Scan /* on child table */
   ... /* Hash Joins (for each child partition) */
```

### Query

The following query is the `UPDATE` statement causing the issue. Basically, the query performs a couple functions using a value from `parent_table` that cannot be nested into a single SQL statement (so two CTEs used), then `UPDATE` the same `parent_table` for the result (the functions are expensive, so the result stored in the table itself).

```
WITH x AS (
  SELECT t."p1", t."p2", f(t."b1") OVER "win_x" AS "c1"
  FROM parent_table AS "t"
  WHERE t."p1" IN ('val1','val2')
  WINDOW "win_x" AS (PARTITION BY "p1" ORDER BY "p1","p2")
), y AS (
  SELECT x."p1", x."p2", f(x."c1") OVER "win_y" AS "c2"
  FROM x
  WINDOW "win_y" AS (PARTITION BY "p1" ORDER BY "p1","p2")
)
UPDATE parent_table AS "t2"
SET ("a1")=(t.”b2”*y."c2")
FROM y INNER JOIN parent_table AS "t" USING ("p1","p2")
WHERE t2."p1"=y."p1" AND t2."p2"=y."p2";
```

### Table definition

Table defined as following:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS parent_table (
   p1   integer,
   p2  timestamp without time zone,
   a1  numeric,
   b1  numeric,
   b2  numeric,
   c1  numeric,
   c2 numeric,
   ... /* additional 8 columns of numeric type */
   z1 numeric,
   z2 numeric,
CONSTRAINT lbound_z1 CHECK ( “z1”::numeric >= 0),
CONSTRAINT lbound_z2 CHECK ( “z2”::numeric >= 0)
PARTITION BY RANGE (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM p2), EXTRACT(MONTH FROM p2))
WITH (OIDS=‘false’)
TABLESPACE ts_ssd_raid10;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS child_table_yyyy_mm PARTITION OF parent_table (
  CONSTRAINT child_pk PRIMARY KEY (p1, p2) WITH (FILLFACTOR=‘90’) USING INDEX TABLESPACE ts_idx_m2ssd
CONSTRAINT child_fk_other_child_yyyy_mm FOREIGN KEY (p1, p2) REFERENCES other_child_yyyy_mm (p1,p2) MATCH FULL WITH (FILLFACTOR=‘90’) USING INDEX TABLESPACE ts_idx_m2ssd )
FOR VALUES FROM (yyyy, mm) TO (yyyy, mm)
WITH (FILLFACTOR=‘90’, OIDS=‘false’)
TABLESPACE ts_ssd_raid10;
ALTER TABLE child_table CLUSTER ON “child_pk”;
```

### Question

How can I perform the `UPDATE` without the nested loop hash joins for each of the 184 child tables?

### System Info

Postgres version 10.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reduced the run time to 1-2sec by using a third CTE:

```
WITH x AS (
  SELECT t."p1", t."p2", t.”b2”, f(t."b1") OVER "win_x" AS "c1"
  FROM parent_table AS "t"
  WHERE t."p1" IN ('val1','val2')
  WINDOW "win_x" AS (PARTITION BY "p1" ORDER BY "p1","p2")
), y AS (
  SELECT x."p1", x."p2", x.”b2”, f(x."c1") OVER "win_y" AS "c2"
  FROM x
  WINDOW "win_y" AS (PARTITION BY "p1" ORDER BY "p1","p2")
), z AS (
  SELECT y.”p1", y.”p2", y.”b2”*y.”c2” AS “a1”
  FROM y
)
UPDATE parent_table AS "t”
SET “a1"=z.”a1”
FROM z
WHERE t.”p1"=z.”p1" AND t.”p2"=z.”p2";
```